# Too much RAM causing BSoD?

Tags: memory, bsod, kernel, computer-building, memory-management

I’ve been building computers for a while now, and I was helping a buddy get his first system together. We got all the hardware in there and tried to boot it up and it blue screened a couple minutes into the process and kept doing this all night, about 20 different stop codes we got, all seeming to relate to memory management and the kernel.

After trying just about everything on planet earth to fix it, we assume it must be a faulty RAM module. So, we start diagnosing stick by stick, and like that, 8 hours of work was for nothing. It worked! So we tested each stick individually and none of them were faulty. So we installed all 4 again (4x8GB) and it crashed instantly. So we removed one stick, and everything runs so smoothly now.

So my question is, does anyone know why this would be happening and how to fix it?

System Specs:

- AMD Ryzen 5 3600
- 4x8GB G.Skill RAM Modules; All The Same
- MSI B450-A Pro Max Mobo

The mother board supports a max of 64GB of memory, any help is appreciated! Ask if you need more details.

Comment: Memory incompatibility can cause BSoD. This effectively means that the memory modules are not the same speed or cas latencies are too different causing weird timing issues, causing BSoD. Best Practice is that all 4 memory modules are from the same brand and same type.

Comment: They are all the same size, speed, and brand. Bought at the same time too.

Comment: One of the pins on the CPU bent?  Also, if you have a different motherboard, see if you can put all 4 sticks in that one and reproduce.

Comment: "So we installed all 4 again (4x8GB) and it crashed instantly. " - This points to a socket issue either due to the specific memory module slot or a memory combability with the memory channel mode.  Ryzen processors are more sensitive to memory compatibility.  What the problem absolutely is NOT caused is having "too much" memory.

Comment: None of the CPU pins are bent, the computer boots up and everything seems like it’s working, we tested different ram slots and all of them are working. My guess would be the compatibility with the modules themselves. I have no clue what else could be causing this. All of our updates are run, we updated the BIOS to the most recent version, not sure what else to check.

Comment: A couple of the BSoD errors we got were IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL, KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED, MEMORY_MANAGEMENT, and SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION are the ones I remember off the top of my head.

Comment: What is the exact model of the RAM sticks? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)